# What is one word to describe an essay that is both fluent,smooth and formal?

Tags: vocabulary

What is one word to describe an essay that precisely describe as fluent,smooth and formal?

It is known that online translation softwares could not translate a phrase like this into vocabulary.

Comment: [treatise](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/treatise) is the closest I can find.

Comment: There is no such single English word that would convey such precise meaning in this context. "Treatise", for example, conveys only the formality aspect. (It would also tend to imply something longer than an "essay").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An adjective for fluent, smooth, and formal?  *Elegant*.

One word for for a fluent, smooth, and formal essay? I like *disquisition*.

But be careful:

> an essay that is both fluent,smooth and formal?

Fluent, smooth, and formal are three things.  The word "both" can only cover two things.